# show dropdownlist items by Image click event?

Tags: jquery

I have one Image and Dropdownlist controls in my page. I am trying to show the dropdownlist items  by click event of the image control.

Is this possible to in JQuery? or give me an alternate way to do this?

this is my HTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Subject, "--")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, new { @data_otf_autocomplete = @Url.Action("Autocomplete_Subject"), @class = "Text_Subject_Name" }) <img src="~/Images/arrow-down.gif" alt="click to choose Subjects" id="arrow" />
```

by clicking on `Image[id='arrow']` should open the `dropdownlist[id=Subject_Name"]` items ?

I got a same example @ http://jsfiddle.net/an3ZT/ based on this example i created below code was not working?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.simulate.js"></script>    


<script type="text/ecmascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("img").click(function () {
            //alert("Hellow world");
            //alert($("select").val());
            $("select").simulate('mousedown');

        });

    });
</script>

 <select>
    <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>    
</select>

<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
```

Please let me know where i did mistake?

Comment: Please include the HTML markup, attempted solutions, why they didn't work and the expected results.

Comment: I am using MVC4 Razor, this is my HTML ` @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Subject, "--")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, new { @data_otf_autocomplete = @Url.Action("Autocomplete_Subject"), @class = "Text_Subject_Name" })    
            <img src="~/Images/arrow-down.gif" alt="click to choose Subjects" id="arrow" />     `

Comment: yes, it's too easy , just use click event in jquery

Comment: by clicking on `Image[id='arrow']` should open the `dropdownlist[id=Subject_Name"]` items ?

Comment: @ Mahmoud Farahat: can you post with example code?

Comment: I don't think its possible ... The max you can do is make a focus on the dropdown list

Comment: also, please add your HTML code in the question itself rather than the comment

Comment: @Vandesh: Sure I have added html code to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An Initial Note To Remember

As a particular solution to the problem of opening the list of a `<select>` element, you cannot natively simulate the events of the mouse trigger; therefore, you need to use the `.simulate` function, however, this is an additional library to jQuery. You will need to import this:

[jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)

### Solution

If you want to trigger an event on any element's click, it is quite easy to do with jQuery.

For example, let's say you have the following image:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg">
```

To trigger any function, you simply have to use `document.ready()` and `img.click`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").click(function(){

        $("select").simulate('mousedown');

    });

});
```

However, this presents a problem when you have more than one `img` element on the page; unless, of course, you want every image to trigger the drop-down list when clicked, it is better to give some specific information to the image element that you want to trigger the list.

This can be accomplished by giving the image an id or a class, or really any attribute to differentiate it from the rest of the images on the page. This can also be used to create a group of image elements that will call the list.

### Using an id:

```
<img id="myImage">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myImage").click(function(){

        $("select").simulate('mousedown');

    });

});
```

### Using a class

#### *You can create groups by giving multiple elements the same class*

```
<img class="myImage">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".myImage").click(function(){

        $("select").simulate('mousedown');

    });

    //OR to be more specific

    $("img.myImage").click(function(){});

});
```

### Using an attribute

You can actually set a custom attribute and use it to differentiate between other images in your html.

```
<img someAttr="useThisOne">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").click(function(){

        if($(this).attr("someAttr") == "useThisOne")
        {
            $("select").simulate('mousedown');
        }
    });

});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/an3ZT/)

Comment: nice lesson on Jquery, but can you please elaborate on the "//Call your dropdown list here" part?

Comment: @David: please see my question. by clicking on Image control Dropdownlist **Items** should show not just focuse on the control.

Comment: I assume that you are using a `<select>` element, correct? Since you cannot truly mimic mouse functions with jQuery, you must call the `mousedown` function of the select element. `$("select").simulate('mousedown');` should get the job done, but note that you will need to import jquery.simulate.js

Comment: @David: `simulate` ? can you elaborate your comment with an working example?

Comment: Check my edit for a link to the fiddle. Click the Google logo to open the dropdown.

Comment: @Vandesh See the link to the JSFiddle in my answer for elaboration and full implementation.

Comment: @David: I am trying to implement my code as per your answer. but it doesn't working for me! can you give any sugesastions? on my updated question with html code?